# Spring error (ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor) on connection with oracle database

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I am running a spring boot application in my local by connecting to oracle database on vm server. Though on testing connection on oracle sql developer it is successful but on running application on same port and credentials it is giving **ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor** error.

Error :- [image]

Setup:-[image]

DB Connection:-[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is malformed that's why it doesn't recognize the db, you have to use:

```
datasource:
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orclcdb
```